# Search field and display next data to it

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Is there an easiest way to search the following data with specific field based on the field `@@id:`?

This is the sample data file called `sample`

```
@@id: 123 @@name: John Doe @@age: 18 @@Gender: Male

@@id: 345 @@name: Sarah Benson @@age: 20 @@Gender: Female
```

For example, If I want to search an ID of 123 and his gender I would do this:

Basically this is the prototype that I want:

```
# search.sh
#!/bin/bash

# usage: search.sh <id> <field>
# eg: search 123 age

search="$1"

field="$2"

grep "^@@id: ${search}" sample | # FILTER <FIELD>
```

So when I search an ID 123 like below:

```
search.sh 123 gender
```

The output would be

```
Male
```

Up until now, based on the code above, I only able to grep one line based on ID, and I'm not sure what is the best method or fastest method with less complicated to get its next value after specifying the field (eg. age)

Comment: Does your files really have `@@id: 123 @@name: John @@age: 18 @@Gender: Male` kind of lines? OR it has like: `123 John 18 Male`? Please confirm once.

Comment: It has that field name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to extract a part of each line found, different from the part you are matching against, `sed` or `awk` would be a better tool than `grep`.  You could pipe the output of `grep` into one of the others, but that's wasteful because both `sed` and `awk` can do the line selection directly.  I would do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

search="$1"
field="$2"

sed -n "/^@@id: ${search}"'\>/ { s/.*@@'"${field}"': *//i; s/ *@@.*//; p }' sample
```

Explanation:

- `sed` is instructed to read file `sample`, which it will do line by line.
- The `-n` option tells `sed` to suppress its usual behavior of automatically outputting its pattern space at the end of each cycle, which is an easy way to filter out lines that don't match the search criterion.
- The `sed` expression starts with an *address*, which in this case is a pattern matching lines by id, according to the script's first argument.  It is much like your `grep` pattern, but I append `\>`, which matches a word boundary.  That way, searches for id 123 will not also match id 1234.
- The rest of the `sed` expression edits out the everything in the line except the value of the requested field, with the field name being matched case-insensitively, and prints the result.  The editing is accomplished by the two `s///` commands, and the `p` command is of course for "print". These are all enclosed in curly braces (`{}`) and separated by semicolons (`;`) to form a single compound associated with the given address.

Comment: I think this answer is perfect because I can shift the field anywhere I like, and it prints every data next to the matching field even the value has spaces.

Comment: I'm glad you like it.

Answer (score 3):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following bash script. This considers that you want to match exact string match.

```
cat script.bash
#!/bin/bash

search="$1"
field="$2"

awk -v search="$search" -v field="$field" '
match($0,"@@id:[[:space:]]*"search){
  value=""
  match($0,"@@"field":[[:space:]]*[^@]+")
  value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*: +/,"",value)
  print value
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you want to search strings(values) irrespective of their cases(lower/upper case) in each line then try following code.

```
cat script.bash
#!/bin/bash

search="$1"
field="$2"

awk -v search="$search" -v field="$field" '
match(tolower($0),"@@id:[[:space:]]*"tolower(search)){
  value=""
  match(tolower($0),"@@"tolower(field)":[[:space:]]*[^@]+")
  value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*: +/,"",value)
  print value
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation of code would be, creating BASH script, which is expecting 2 parameters while its being run. Then passing these parameters as values to `awk` program. Then using `match` function to match the id in each line and print the value of passed field(eg: name OR Gender etc).

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13, is there a way to make the output prints spaces value? For example if the name is John Doe, this would only print John

Comment: @KalibZen, sure I have modified my code now, kindly do check it once and let me know if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks I wish I could accept this as the 2nd best answer. I've seen a lot of your posts about `awk`.. you are the master.

Comment: @KalibZen, Not an issue, Happy to help here(I am also a learner like we all here :) ). Keep learning and keep sharing cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- 'label' fields have format `@@<string>:`
- need to handle case-insensitive searches
- 'label' fields could be located anywhere in the line (ie, there is no set ordering of 'label' fields)
- the 1st input search parameter is always a value associated with the `@@id:` label
- the 2nd input search parameter is to be matched as a whole word (ie, no partial label matching; `nam` will not match against `@@name:`)
- if there are multiple 'label' fields that match the 2nd input search parameter we print the value associated with the 1st match found in the line)

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v search="${search}" -v field="${field}" '
BEGIN    { field = tolower(field) }
         { n=split($0,arr,"@@|:")                             # split current line on dual delimiters "@@" and ":", place fields into array arr[]

           found_search = 0
           found_field  = 0

           for (i=2;i<=n;i=i+2) {                             # loop through list of label fields
               label=tolower(arr[i])
               value = arr[i+1]
               sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",value)                  # strip leading white space
               sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"",value)                  # strip trailing white space

               if ( label == "id"  &&   value == search ) 
                  found_search = 1
               if ( label == field && ! found_field )
                  found_field  = value
           }

           if ( found_search && found_field )
              print found_field
         }
' sample
```

Sample input:

```
$ cat sample
@@id: 123 @@name: John Doe @@age: 18 @@Gender: Male
@@id: 345 @@name: Sarah Benson @@age: 20 @@Gender: Female
@@name:    Archibald P. Granite, III, Ph.D, M.D.    @@age: 20 @@Gender: not specified @@id: 567
```

Test runs:

```
search=123 field=gender  => Male
search=123 field=ID      => 123
search=123 field=Age     => 18
search=345 field=name    => Sarah Benson
search=567 field=name    => Archibald P. Granite, III, Ph.D, M.D.
search=567 field=GENDER  => not specified
search=999 field=age     => <no output>
```

Comment: Thanks this is working but has many limitation. One example if I shift the `@@id:` into the last field, and this script need to be changed.

Comment: updated. sorry about that. because I tried to make the input file as simple as possible but I forgot that should be the case

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, eventhough it has limitation this due to my question was not properly updated with sample data but I learned a lot through your sample code with best explanation there. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

For the given data format, you could set the field separator to optional spaces followed by `@@` to prevent trailing spaces for the printed field.

Then create a key value mapping per row (making the keys and the field to search for lowercase) and search for the key, which will be independent of the order in the string.

If the key is present, then print the value.

```
#!/bin/bash

search="$1"
field="$2"

awk -v search="${search}" -v field="${field}" '
BEGIN {FS="[[:blank:]]*@@"}                      # Set field separator to optional spaces and @@
{
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {                    # Loop all the fields
    split($i, a, /[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*/)    # Split the field on : with optional surrounded spaces
    kv[tolower(a[1])]=a[2]                       # Create a key value array using the splitted values
  }
  val = kv[tolower(field)]                       # Get the value from kv based on the lowercase key
  if (kv["id"] == search && val) print val       # If there is a matching key and a value, print the value
}' file
```

And then run

```
./search.sh 123 gender
```

Output

```
Male
```